# system verilog - uvm - wait for pkt in sequence

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm running in system-verilog in uvm.
I'm want to send a request in my sequence and to wait for a response pkt. how can i do it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence sends a request to the sequencer when you create and randomize a transaction. The sequencer then sends the transaction to the driver and driver sends the response back using method put_response(rsp). In your sequence you can use the method get_response(rsp) which is a blocking call and wait till the driver sends a response back. This is well explained [here](http://www.testbench.in/UT_07_UVM_SEQUENCE_1.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is what's known as a slave sequence. You send a dummy request from the sequence first, then (normally from the driver) you send a response back to the sequence which essentially swaps the meaning of request/response. An example can be found [here](https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/sequences/slave).